# want to count the items in column

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I have created a function that outputs the unique values of a given column.

```
def unique(col):
    print(col.capitalize(), 'unique values')
    print()
    count = 0

for i in df2[col].unique():
    count = count + 1
    print(count, i)

unique('sex')
```

The output looks like:

Sex unique values

```
1 Male Characters
2 Female Characters
3 Genderfluid Characters
4 Agender Characters
```

I would like to include a count of the unique items in the column, so it would look something like this:

```
1 Male Characters 8790
```

Comment: Easiest way to get unique items in a column is `df["col_name"].value_counts()`

Comment: Can you share with us your DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code. The function wouldn't be necessary at all.

```
print(df['column_name'].value_counts())
```

This directly gives you the unique values and how often they occur.